# Navigation menu URLs customization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have existing Sharepoint 2010 website with the below code in master page for navigation menu:

```
    <PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource 
            ID="topSiteMap" 
            runat="server" 
            EnableViewState="false" 
            SiteMapProvider="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider" 
            StartFromCurrentNode="true" 
            StartingNodeOffset="0" 
            ShowStartingNode="true" 
            TrimNonCurrentTypes="Heading"/> 
    <SharePoint:AspMenu 
            ID="TopNavigationMenuV4" 
            Runat="server" 
            EnableViewState="false" 
            DataSourceID="topSiteMap" 
            UseSimpleRendering="true" 
            UseSeparateCss="false" 
            Orientation="Horizontal" 
            StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2" 
            SkipLinkText="" 
            CssClass="s4-tn"> 
    </SharePoint:AspMenu>
```

It renders menu items with hyper-links like below (hyper-link is not including a web page):

```
<a class="static dynamic-children menu-item" href="/products">
```

This causes unwanted server redirect when user clicks a menu item.
How can I make all menu item hyper-links to end with "**default.aspx**" (like below)?

```
<a class="static dynamic-children menu-item" href="/products/default.aspx">
```

Thanks, 
Boris

Answer (score 0):

create a custom sitemapprovider ;)

How come you get unwanted redirects? Are the homepages of the sites set to default.aspx?